# Теряется сессия при вызове сервлета

Tags: java, сессия, servlet

Прохожу авторизацию через JDBCRealm/j_security_check. Создается сессия, на странице вызываю request.getUserPrincipal().getName(), возвращает логин, как мне и надо, но если вызываю сервлет и в нем вызываю эту функцию, то возвращает null, собственно как и функция request.getSession(false). Вопрос такой: почему при вызове сервлета сессия теряется и как можно ее передать?

Comment: Сервлет же вызывается до сессии? getSession(false) не поможет создать сессию. С параметром false в лучшем случае вернётся сессия, которая открыта заранее. Для того чтобы создать сессию используется getSession(true) (или просто getSession())

Comment: Нет, сервлет вызывается после успешной авторизации.

Comment: Авторизация сама по себе не приводит к созданию никакой сессии.

Comment: Как тогда мне получить логин, с помощью которого авторизировались, если на главной странице я его могу получить, а при вызове сервлета нет?

Comment: На странице ли (JSP?), в сервлете ли, на который переходит форма ввода логина вызываете getSession(). После этого сессия будет везде. А лучше в фильтре

Comment: При использовании j_security_check сессия вызывается нормально, в том то и дело. Сервлет, который я использую, никак не связан с авторизацией, но в нем надо получить логин. Если вызову в нем новую сессию, то разве смогу получить логин?

Comment: request.getUserPrincipal().getName() - вот это называете удачным вызовом сессии:)))

Comment: тогда я совсем не понимаю, почему request.getUserPrincipal().getName() работает на главной странице, а в сервлете нет))

Comment: Протокол http так устроен, что нет в нем никаких сессий. Авторизации подвергается каждый запрос. И java не нарушает эту "традицию". Серверу плевать что на прошлом запросе request.getUserPrincipal().getName() работал, а на следующем нет. Пока сами в нужное время не создадите сессию. И секурити в Вашем web.xml наверняка обходят сервлет стороной

Comment: тогда как мне узнать логин человека, который будет загружать файл( это то, что делает мой сервлет)?

Comment: Так же. request.getUserPrincipal().getName(). Только надо всё правильно сделать. Что ещё сказать, если не известно что у Вас есть

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое, буду разбираться.